# Modify or Create paper_trail version with alternate attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I have a model with a start_date and end_date.

When a version is created, if the old end_date is after the new start_date then the end_date in the paper_trail version should be set to start_date of the updated record

In sudo code this might look like...

(doesn't work and I'd prefer to not modify the version after creating it)

```
record.save
version = paper_trail.previous_version
if (version.end_date > record.start_date)
  version.end_date = record.start_date
  version.save
end
```

The sequence would look like this...

Create record

```
record: start_date=2021, end_date=nil
```

Update record

```
record: start_date=2022, end_date=2023
version1: start_date=2021, end_date=2022
```

Update record

```
record: start_date=2024, end_date=2037
version2: start_date=2022, end_date=2024
version1: start_date=2021, end_date=2022
```

rails 6.1, paper_trail 12

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the Papertrail behavior as-is, meaning it would keep track of value changes for each field without any additional custom logic that would overwrite the values, thus breaking interface for rolling back to a version etc.

Instead, I would use `meta` to store and retrieve any custom data you need for the model https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata

Comment: Thanks, meta was helpful. All I have to do is replace the incorrect data after reify

Comment: But let's say I am changing IDs, and I want papertrail to not display the IDs, but instead display the corresponding names from a different table, and I have several of them like paying_company_ids, registered_company_ids, where I want to have this altered behavior. 

If I used metadata and stored the names, how would I replicate the behavior of object wherein it only displays the stuff that changed? Having separate column for metadata would mean, it would display names even if it didn't change, right?

Comment: @FiFi I would suggest creating a new question and elaborating on the `behavior of object wherein it only displays the stuff that changed?` - it's unclear where do you see this behaviour, if it is Rails or Papertrail specific.

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472789/overriding-object-changes-on-paper-trails-to-store-name-corresponding-to-change . Sometimes I could have both paying_id & company_ids or I could have either one. How to have the name in the meta data update whenever the corresponding ID updates in the object_changes?